# Change default admin page for specific role(s)

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles, dashboard

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin or a way programmatically to change the the default admin page for a specific user/role?

I have a master panel page for my plugin currently setup with custom roles and permissions for the plugin using the [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members) and would like to force users that are in these custom roles to use my master control panel for their dashboard because they don't necessarily need access to the Dashboard.

**Minor Edit**: Along with changing the default dashboard for the roles, is there a way to disable the WordPress dashboard?

-Zack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your theme's *functions.php*:

```
function hide_the_dashboard()
{
    global $current_user;
    // is there a user ?
    if ( is_array( $current_user->roles ) ) {
        // substitute your role(s):
        if ( in_array( 'custom_role', $current_user->roles ) ) {
            // hide the dashboard:
            remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_the_dashboard' );

function your_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    // is there a user ?
    if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        // substitute your role(s):
        if ( in_array( 'custom_role', $user->roles ) ) {
            // pick where to redirect to, in the example: Posts page
            return admin_url( 'edit.php' );
        } else {
            return admin_url();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'your_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin.

> This plugin themes the WordPress login, registration and forgot
> password pages according to your current theme. It creates a page to
> use in place of wp-login.php, using a page template from your theme.
> Also includes a widget for sidebar login.
>
> **Features**
>
> - ...
> - Redirect users upon log in and log out based upon their role
> - ...

Answer (score 1):

Ad Dashboard: You could check the $_REQUEST and depending on what you get back, simply use [wp_redirect();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)