# change Dashboard default page on login

Tags: php, users, login, dashboard, cms

I found almost the same question here - [Remove dashboard, use Pages tab as default](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39087/remove-dashboard-use-pages-tab-as-default?newreg=806a3f51e7b244768fdbdacfad5be809)

and I tried to implement it for my own needs and couldn't get it to work.

I am doing a hotel site and I am making a dashboard for the hotel workers. I have it set so there is only the booking plugin available in the dashboard menu, but I would like it to show the "all bookings" page (not the default, widgets, as they don't need any). I tried this as the code (below) and it didn't work - The url I took from after clicking on the submenu item "all bookings" (I also tried `edit.php?post_type=mphb_booking`) and the user I got from inspecting the Hotel Manager role in Users. Any help is appreciated.

```
function dashboard_redirect($url) {
    global $current_user;
    // is there a user ?
    if(is_array($current_user->roles)) {
        // check, whether user has the author role:
        if(in_array('mphb_manager', $current_user->roles)) {
             $url = admin_url('edit.php?post_type=mphb_booking&uipid=637');
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'dashboard_redirect');
```